# How to sort by column of tableview in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, tableview

There is a tableview in my application. It has 2 columns, one is "key" and one is "value", the code for tableview is as below:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    //DataEntity *dataEntity = [[DataEntity alloc]init];
    return [dataEntity.items count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    //DataEntity *dataEntity = [[DataEntity alloc]init];
    if([[tableColumn identifier]isEqualToString:@"key"])
    {
        return [[dataEntity.items allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    if([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"value"])
    {
        return [[dataEntity.items allValues] objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

dataEntity is a signle instance of the data source and items  is a mutable dictianary. Now i want to sort by one column after i click the header of that column. How to implement it?
I try to do it as below, but it doesn't work.

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView mouseDownInHeaderOfTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
{
    NSImage *indicatorImage;
    if(sortAscending)
    {
    indicatorImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"NSAscendingSortIndicator"];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [tempDict setDictionary:dataEntity.items];
        NSLog(@"before sort %@",tempDict);
    NSArray *keys =  [tempDict allKeys];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1,id obj2){
        return ([obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch]);
    }];

    [dataEntity.items setDictionary:tempDict];

    }
    else
    {
    indicatorImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"NSDescendingSortIndicator"];
    }
    sortAscending=!sortAscending;
    [tableView setIndicatorImage:indicatorImage inTableColumn:tableColumn];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is through IB, just select the table columns and attribute inspector, and then set the "sort Key" to the property that represents the value in your dictionary.

[image]